# Raise TypeError (TypeError: object of type <class 'numpy.float64'> cannot be safely interpreted as an integer)

Tags: python, numpy, package, numpy-ufunc

I am using a package that needs NumPy. Until now it was working fine. But today, because of extending my code I needed the newest version of NumPy. The old version was 17.something and I installed the latest version. After that I am facing the below mentioned issue [The detailed link of the question on Github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/15345#issue-551771795)

```
 File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\function_base.py", line 119, in linspace
  raise TypeError(
TypeError: object of type <class 'numpy.float64'> cannot be safely interpreted as an integer.
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Identify the expression that has the problem, and the variable (such as an index) that should be an integer, but actually comes from a float dtype array.  Newer numpy has tightened up some automatic conversions from the past.

Comment: @AMC the code is from a package named cosmoTransitions(which consists of 4-5 different codes)[https://github.com/clwainwright/CosmoTransitions](https://github.com/clwainwright/CosmoTransitions)

Comment: When is this error occurring, then?

Comment: Looks like this is due to a change in 1.18.  In previous versions (e.g. 1.17) the use of a float for the `num` in `linspace` produced a deprecation warning (which may be ignored).  In the latest this was changed to an error.  The easiest fix is probably to revert to an earlier numpy version.  When using third party libraries, using the latest numpy is not always the best idea.  It takes a while to work out the incompatibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade your **numpy** version to: **1.16**

**pip install numpy==1.16**

worked for me .

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this error and downgrading is not required.

```
np.linspace(0,1,int(10.))
```

the `num` value needs to be passed as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

In a 1.17 numpy

```
In [216]: np.linspace(0,1,10.)                                                                   
Out[216]: 
array([0.        , 0.11111111, 0.22222222, 0.33333333, 0.44444444,
       0.55555556, 0.66666667, 0.77777778, 0.88888889, 1.        ])
```

update to 1.18

```
In [2]: np.linspace(0,10,10.)                                                                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/function_base.py in linspace(start, stop, num, endpoint, retstep, dtype, axis)
    116     try:
--> 117         num = operator.index(num)
    118     except TypeError:

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-1e9a5a5e4a05> in <module>
----> 1 np.linspace(0,10,10.)

<__array_function__ internals> in linspace(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/function_base.py in linspace(start, stop, num, endpoint, retstep, dtype, axis)
    119         raise TypeError(
    120             "object of type {} cannot be safely interpreted as an integer."
--> 121                 .format(type(num)))
    122 
    123     if num < 0:

TypeError: object of type <class 'float'> cannot be safely interpreted as an integer.
```

That `num = operator.index(num)` test used to be in a `deprecation` warning function, `num = _index_deprecate(num)`, now it raises an error.

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.17.0/numpy/core/function_base.py#L37-L179

Answer (score 0):

pycocotools/cocoeval.py 
add int() to third parameter of np.linspace() 
Change lines 507 and 508 like below:

```
    self.iouThrs = np.linspace(.5, 0.95, int(np.round((0.95 - .5) / .05)) + 1, endpoint=True)
    self.recThrs = np.linspace(.0, 1.00, int(np.round((1.00 - .0) / .01)) + 1, endpoint=True)
```